# how to programmatically perform segue, or present view, when button pressed in swift3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

I'm coding an app programatically (no storyboard) and have login screen. the login screen has input boxes for the user details to login and a login and register button.

How do I programatically interact with the buttons to effectively perform a segue to a new view once a button is pressed?

I know that for a navigation button I would use

```
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleLogout))
```

but is there an equivalent for any button in the view controller? I'm sure there is, and its probably a simple question, but any help would be appreciated.

my button code is

```
let registerButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        button.setTitle("Register", for: .normal)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return button
    }()
```

and is added to the login page as a subview

```
view.addSubview(registerButton)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`segue` is Interface Builder lingo. In iOS, you can only display a view controller three ways: `push`, `present`, `show`. Programmatically, you wouldn't call it segue. First, add a target to your button:

```
registerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(registerButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Create the action method:

```
@objc func registerButtonAction() {
    ...
}
```

And if you want to `push` to a view controller (using a navigation controller), push to it from inside the action method:

```
@objc func registerButtonAction() {
    let destination = SomeViewController()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
}
```

If you want to present it (modally):

```
@objc func registerButtonAction() {
    let destination = SomeViewController()
    destination.transitioningDelegate = SomePresentationAnimationVendor() // for custom presentations
    destination.modalPresentationStyle = .custom // for custom
    present(destination, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I have accepted the answer because it gave me the idea of how to solve the problem. But in registerButtonAction I needed to use 'present(destination, animated: true, completion: nil)' method. I also printed some text to make sure the method was always getting called, and it was, but for some reason the 'navigationConrtoller?.pushViewController...' line of code was not pushing to my new VC. any ideas why this could be?

Comment: It must be because you don't have your `UINavigationController` properly set up.

Answer (score 1):

Add a target to you button so that a function is executed when the button is tapped.

```
registerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.registerTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Create the function `registerTapped`.

```
// Swift 4 requires @objc
@objc func registerTapped(_ sender: UIButton){  
    // Segue here
}
```

Write your segue code and place it inside `registerTapped`

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueName", sender: nil)
```

All together now

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    registerButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.registerTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside) 
}

@objc func registerTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {  
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueName", sender: nil)
}
```

Comment: I have upvoted  because I had a customised rightbarbuttontem as button and it was not registering touches, though data was transferred to secondviewcontroller i.e performseguewithidentifier was partially working, but the push action with the performseguewithidentifier was not working. Now, I have two segues in my viewcontroller, one to transfer data and another (yours) to register touch and push. Anyways, its working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should write function for your button and assign it to button

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  ...
  button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
}

func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
  print("Button tapped")
}
```